# python2.7 project to exe Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

programming environment is Eclipse+pydev，python2.7.5，GUI use wxPython，running in eclipse is all ok，I want to pack the programming to .exe，but tragedy happened....

I use three tools to do that:

1. in py2exe：
   py2exe tell me some module is missing：

   **The following modules appear to be missing
    ['Carbon', 'Carbon.Files', 'OpenSSL.SSL', '_scproxy', '_sysconfigdata', 'builtin
    s', 'chardet', 'cjkcodecs.aliases', 'http.client', 'http.cookiejar', 'http.cooki
    es', 'iconv_codec', 'mx', 'ndg.httpsclient.ssl_peer_verification', 'ndg.httpscli
    ent.subj_alt_name', 'packages.ssl_match_hostname.CertificateError', 'packages.ss
    l_match_hostname.match_hostname', 'pyasn1.codec.der', 'queue', 'urllib.parse', '
    urllib.request']**

   but I remember that i haven't use these package，especially， some package such as the urllib.request even can't be found in the package urllib！
   when ignore this package， run the exe， it will report error：

   i don't know how to solve this problem...
2. in cx_freeze:
   the problem is same as in py2exe
3. in pyinstaller:
   no error in pack the code, but when run the exe, the error is reported:
   **"UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode bytes in position 22-23: illegal mu
   ltibyte sequence"**

   It seems it is the chinese char leads to the errror, but I have added "# -*- coding:UTF-8" before all my codes. and the eclipse 's environment has been set to be utf-8.

I don't know what to do, anyone could help me?  thank you!!

Comment: `urllib.request` is part of the Python 3 layout. Most likely, some module you're using supports Python 2 and 3, and the freeze tools are trying the imports for both variants. At least in cx_Freeze, the warnings about missing modules can be ignored if it produces an executable anyway.